# Get Client external IP or Client LAN IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, webrequest

```
public static string GetClientExternalIp()
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
        if (addresses.Length != 0)
        {
            return addresses[0];
        }
    }
    return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

I am struggling with the above code snippet, i want to get the client external IP address like what you see when browse to http://checkip.dyndns.org but above snippet returns the IP address of the Server. What i need is the IP address of the LAN the client is connecting from NOT the web server IP.

Comment: What is "the" webserver? Do you mean the server running this code returns its own IP address? How do you clients request the page running this code?

Comment: @CodeCastery: Yes the server running this code returns its own IP address. The clients request the page from a multiple company private networks/domains.

Answer (score 0):

Use [HttpRequest.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

I use the above line of code and it returns the clients IP address.

Comment: I guess this will return the local IP not the client external IP, right?

Comment: For me this code returns exactly the same IP as the link you've provided

Answer (score -2):

Try this..
This works for me.

By using this method you can get the client IP address instead of Server IP.

```
public static string GetClientIP()
{
    try
    {
        string VisitorsIPAddress = string.Empty;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null)
        {
            VisitorsIPAddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        }
        else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
        {
            VisitorsIPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        }
        return VisitorsIPAddress;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have added some more to make it understandable. This is not what OP is looking for